# NODE.JS - passing pathname using URL.parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, url-routing

In the following code I'm creating an API and I want to pass a pathname and check it using switch statements to pass GET, POST, etc.

But it seems I am doing something wrong because it doesn't seem to pass the pathname but the localhost:8080..

```
var http = require('http');
var URL = require('URL');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var parsedURL = URL.parse(req.URL, true);

    switch (parsedURL) {
        case '/api/something':
        if (parsedURL.query.id) {
            findProductById(id, req, res);
        }
        else {
            findAll(req, res);
        }
        break;
        default;
        res.end('End of connection');
    }
});
server.listen(8080);
console.log("Running");
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I using the URL properly? Or missing something with the parsing?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `switch(parsedURL.pathname) {` if you want the pathname?

Comment: What is the value you are getting for req.URL?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - yes it should :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your require should look like this:

```
var URL = require('url');
```

Node couldn't find the right module, it's all lowercase.

Also, the default statement in your switch case is using improper syntax. Try:

```
default: res.end('End of connection');
```

Comment: this definitely helped, as nodemon has been showing me that cannot find url module and I did not know what was that and obviously that stupid syntax, but it still seems not working...